# Add dictionary file to postgresql docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, full-text-search

I am using the postgresql docker image

https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

To improve my full text search experience with a synonym dictionary according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-SYNONYM-DICTIONARY, I have to put a file into `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data` which happens to be folder `/usr/share/postgresql/9.5/tsearch_data` in the docker image.

How can I do that while minimizing the set up burden for another user? (Sure I always can docker exec -it  bash to add that file manually)

1. Create an own docker image derived from
   https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
   In that case, how can I add a file into that image while keeping all other setup steps as they are?
2. Maybe the init script from the Postgresql-Image will be helpful for me?

   ```
   If you would like to do additional initialization in an image
   derived from this one, add one or more *.sql or *.sh scripts
   under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   ```

   (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/, "How to extend this image")

Comment: Just create a Dockerfile, `FROM postgres` `ADD local_file /usr/share/postgresql/9.5/tsearch_data/`, and then build an image using `docker build -t postgres_with_dictionary .`. Put the local_file in the same folder as the Dockerfile (ideally in a new folder with no other files), and build from that folder)

Comment: @warmoverflow thank you for the quick reply, I am astonished how easy that actually is, thank you for putting me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with Docker, you can use `FROM postgres` in an entirely new Dockerfile, which will use everything from that image, but with your new directives/layers added onto it. So you can then add a new layer that copies this file to the image with something like this:

```
COPY tsearch_data /usr/share/postgresql/9.5/tsearch_data
```

You should prefer `COPY` over `ADD` per [best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

This is pretty self-explanatory, but once you build the new image from this Dockerfile (e.g. `docker build -t=myPostgres .`) -- making sure that your `tsearch_data` file is in the same directory as your Dockerfile -- your new image can be pushed to Docker Hub (or private registry, or in a tarball, or whatever distribution method you use), and that new Postgres image now containers your `tsearch_data` file, while also retaining everything from the original Dockerfile.